# My hour is returning 0 when the time reaches after 00h :59m : 59s

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having a problem in this javascript computation of hour, when the time reaches 1 hour it goes back to 00:00:00 then counts up again. even when i hardcoded it on my html, it just keep on returning to 00 h. help me please!

Here is the code:

```js
$('.countup').each(function() {
  var targetdate = $(this).children("#targetdate").html();
  //var seconds_left = new Date(targetdate).getTime();

  var seconds_left = new Date(targetdate).getTime();
  var timer = $(this).children('#timer');
  var count = $(this);
  var hoursv = '',
    minsv = '',
    secsv = '';
  var hours, minutes, seconds;

  seconds_left = seconds_left / 1000;

  var countdownrefesh = setInterval(function() {
    // Add one to seconds
    seconds_left = seconds_left + 1;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    if (hours < 10) {
      hoursv = "0" + hours;
    } else {
      hoursv = hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minsv = "0" + minutes;
    } else {
      minsv = minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
      secsv = "0" + seconds;
    } else {
      secsv = seconds;
    }

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    s = hours + minutes + seconds;
    t = hoursv + " h :" + minsv + " h :" + secsv + " s";
    timer.html(t)

    if (minutes > 10 && minutes <= 15 && hours >= 0) {
      count.attr('style', 'background-color: orange');
    } else if (minutes > 15 && hours >= 0) {
      count.attr('style', 'background-color: red');
    } else {
      count.attr('style', 'background-color: green');
    }

  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div class="countup">
  <div id="targetdate" style="display: none">Thu Jan 01 1970 01:31:51 +0000</div>
  <span id="timer"></span>
</div>
<div class="countup">
  <div id="targetdate" style="display: none">Thu Jan 01 1970 00:59:49 +0000</div>
  <span id="timer"></span>
</div>
<div class="countup">
  <div id="targetdate" style="display: none">Thu Jan 01 1970 00:10:58 +0000</div>
  <span id="timer"></span>
</div>
<div class="countup">
  <div id="targetdate" style="display: none">Thu Jan 01 1970 00:05:58 +0000</div>
  <span id="timer"></span>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID, which is invalid. Start by fixing that. Also, you should not parse strings with the Date constructor. Write a function or use a library.

Comment: Why are you calling `parseInt()` on the result of dividing? That returns a number, not a string. Use `Math.floor()` to get the integer part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
```

So after the first iteration, the seconds never go above 3600.

Note that using *setInterval* this way is not advised, as it slowly drifts. You use multiple elements with the same ID, which is invalid and should be avoided. Also, this is very inefficient as it sets up a separate timer for each *countup* element.

Consider instead (no jQuery):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var counters = document.querySelectorAll('.countup');
  var targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.countup .targetdate'));
  var dates = targets.map(function(t){return new Date(t.textContent)});
  var timers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.countup .timer'));
  function formatTime(seconds) {
    function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
    seconds = seconds % 86400;
    return z(seconds/3600|0) + ' h: ' +
           z((seconds%3600)/60|0) + ' m: ' + 
           z((seconds%60)) + ' s'; 
  }
  setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    timers.forEach(function(timer, i) {
      timer.textContent = formatTime((now - dates[i])/1000|0);
    });
  }, 1000)
};
```

```html
<div class="countup">
  <div class="targetdate" style="display: none">Thu Jan 01 1970 01:31:51 +0000</div>
  <span class="timer"></span>
</div>
<div class="countup">
  <div class="targetdate" style="display: none">Thu Jan 01 1970 00:59:49 +0000</div>
  <span class="timer"></span>
</div>
<div class="countup">
  <div class="targetdate" style="display: none">Thu Jan 01 1970 00:10:58 +0000</div>
  <span class="timer"></span>
</div>
<div class="countup">
  <div class="targetdate" style="display: none">Thu Jan 01 1970 00:05:58 +0000</div>
  <span class="timer"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you divide `seconds_left` by 86400 and 3600 when you're calculating `hours` and `minutes`. You need to use a different variable during the calculations than the one you're using to hold the time between iterations of the `setInterval` function.

```js
$('.countup').each(function() {
  var targetdate = $(this).children("#targetdate").html();
  //var seconds_left = new Date(targetdate).getTime();

  var seconds_left = new Date(targetdate).getTime();
  var timer = $(this).children('#timer');
  var count = $(this);
  var hoursv = '',
    minsv = '',
    secsv = '';
  var hours, minutes, seconds;

  seconds_left = seconds_left / 1000;

  var countdownrefesh = setInterval(function() {
    // Add one to seconds
    seconds_left = seconds_left + 1;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    var cur_seconds = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(cur_seconds / 3600);
    cur_seconds = cur_seconds % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(cur_seconds / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(cur_seconds % 60);

    if (hours < 10) {
      hoursv = "0" + hours;
    } else {
      hoursv = hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minsv = "0" + minutes;
    } else {
      minsv = minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
      secsv = "0" + seconds;
    } else {
      secsv = seconds;
    }

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    s = hours + minutes + seconds;
    t = hoursv + " h :" + minsv + " h :" + secsv + " s";
    timer.html(t)

    if (minutes > 10 && minutes <= 15 && hours >= 0) {
      count.attr('style', 'background-color: orange');
    } else if (minutes > 15 && hours >= 0) {
      count.attr('style', 'background-color: red');
    } else {
      count.attr('style', 'background-color: green');
    }

  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div class="countup">
  <div id="targetdate" style="display: none">Thu Jan 01 1970 01:31:51 +0000</div>
  <span id="timer"></span>
</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```